# Ubuntu 17.10 / Gnome Shell - xmodmap does not work

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-shell

I recently switched to ubuntu17.10 with the new gnome shell.
With my old `.Xmodmap` file containing:

```
keycode 66 = Mode_switch

keysym apostrophe =  apostrophe quotedbl adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keysym semicolon = semicolon colon odiaeresis Odiaeresis 
keysym bracketleft = bracketleft braceleft udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keysym minus = minus underscore ssharp
```

The `Mode_switcch` does not work anymore (so I can't type in any `adiaresis` anymore)
I suppose, the gnome shell somehow grabs my capslock.
Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: I experience this as well. Switching back to unity helped.

Comment: I have the same problem, how do you solved it?

Comment: @Brutus I ve posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

In the **login screen** click the gear (for settings) and select x11 instead of Wayland. Then it works again.

The problem is that `xmodmap` is part of Xorg, if you run it  like that it works out

https://itsfoss.com/switch-xorg-wayland/

(It is still not a full solution, but I hope that one day wayland will support xmodmap-like utility)

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. That explains why my xmodmap files stopped working. I found a solution, that works with Wayland using `xkb`: https://askubuntu.com/a/1007440